# iOS Safari/Chrome focusing HTML Selects Freezes the browser

Tags: ios, html, google-chrome, mobile-safari, html-select

I saw that a similar question has been asked awhile ago, but it never had a real solution.

I have a page with about 30-40 inputs/selects. Some of them are within hidden divs at some points. The inputs don't give me any problems. But, sometimes when clicking one of the 10 selects, the browser locks up (in Safari and Chrome). It doesn't always do it, but when it does the browser usually crashes or is frozen for about 20-30 seconds.

Is there any known Solution to fix this problem? Is there any way to get around this without making some custom designed select options with html/javascript?

I don't have any hidden inputs by the way.